# Can't write command into my DataOutputStream

Tags: java, android

I can't write my command into my `DataOutputStream` because it needs datatype `BYTES`, how can i get the bytes from my command?

```
"tinymix" -> toBytes
"exit" -> toBytes
```

I somehow need to convert this to Bytes, but how?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});

        DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();

        stdin.write("tinymix\n"); // THIS LINE IS BROKEN
        stdin.write("exit\n");   // THIS LINE IS BROKEN

        stdin.flush();
        stdin.close();
```

Comment: So your problem is that you do want to write a String but the write method only accepts integers?

Comment: stdin.write only accepts bytes, but i've got a string

Comment: @Selvin I use this to get the output from the command that i executed, why do u say that there is no sense? My code now works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getBytes()` on a string object to get the string as bytes

Change this

```
stdin.write("tinymix\n"); // THIS LINE IS BROKEN
stdin.write("exit\n");   // THIS LINE IS BROKEN
```

into this

```
stdin.write("tinymix\n".getBytes());
stdin.write("exit\n".getBytes());
```

Comment: Wow is that really working right now xD, wow is that simple, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can write a string with (for example) a `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
OutputStreamWriter stdin= new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
```

instread of using a `DataOutputStream`.

Your code would look like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});

OutputStreamWriter stdin = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();

stdin.write("tinymix\n");
stdin.write("exit\n");

stdin.flush();
stdin.close();
```

Comment: This should be an answer ... OP is missusing the DataOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
stdin.writeUTF("str");
```

That allows you to write strings using DataOutputStream

Then you can use

```
std.readUTF();
```

to read your string back